# Get document vector count in a pdf document?

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I have a problem with some user provided pdf documents.  They are created from 3d packages and are basically a HUGE list of vector lines that take and age to render (over 60 secs).

How can I generate a report on the number of vector lines present in a pdf document using [iTextSharp (5.0.5)](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/)?

I can get text and image data but can't see where to get a handle on vector.  They don't seems to be represented as an image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iText[Sharp]'s parser package doesn't yet handle lineTo or curveTo commands.  It's a goal, but not one that's been important enough to implement as yet.  Other Things are getting attention at the moment.

If you're feeling adventurous, you should check out PdfContentStreamProcessor.  In a private function `populateOperators`, there's a long list of commands that are currently handled (in one fashion or another).

You'd need to write similar command classes for all the line art commands (moveTo, lineTo, rect, stroke, fill, clip), and expose them in some way.

Actually, if all you want to do is COUNT the number of paths, you could just implement stroke and fill to increment some static integer[s], then check them after parsing.  Should be fairly simple (I'm writing in Java, but it's easy enough to translate):

```
private static class CountOps implements ContentOperator {
  public static int operationCount = 0;
  public void invoke(PdfContentStreamProcessor processor, PdfLiteral operator, ArrayList<PdfObject> operands) {
    ++operationCount;
  }
}
```

Ah!  `registerContentOperator` is a public function.  You don't need to change iText's source at all:

```
PdfContentStreamProcessor proc = new PdfContentStreamProcessor(null);
CountOps counter = new CountOps();
proc.registerContentOperator("S", countOps); // stroke the path
proc.registerContentOperator("s", countOps); // close & stroke
proc.registerContentOperator("F", countOps); // fill, backward compat
proc.registerContentOperator("f", countOps); // fill
proc.registerContentOperator("f*", countOps); // fill with event-odd winding rule
proc.registerContentOperator("B", countOps); // fill & stroke
proc.registerContentOperator("B*", countOps); // fill & stroke with even-odd
proc.registerContentOperator("b", countOps); // close, fill, & stroke
proc.registerContentOperator("b*", countOps); // close, fill, & stroke with even-odd

proc.processContent( contentBytes, pageResourceDict );

int totalStrokesAndFills = CountOps.operationCount; // note that stroke&fill operators will be counted once, not twice.
```

Something like that.  Only a null RenderListener will cause a null pointer exception if you run into any text or images.  You could whip up a no-op listener yourself or use one of the existing ones and ignore its output.

PS: iTextSharp 5.0.6 should be released any day now if it isn't out already.

Comment: Hi, I figured out a quick way along the same lines. in the while (tokenizer.NextToken()) loop I can look for tokentype "OTHER" and compare the tokenizer string values against a list or vector operations values (includes above but also has "l", "c", "v", "y", "h", "re". It 'seems to work fairly well since my goal is mainly to identify documents that will take a while to render. iText in Action, Second Edition was a good help

Comment: I did also implement an IRenderListener to grab image counts and dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

There is no specific Vector image. Normally it is just added to the content stream which is essentially a Vector data stream for drawing the whole page.

There is a blog article which you might find useful for understanding this at http://www.jpedal.org/PDFblog/2010/11/grow-your-own-pdf-file-%E2%80%93-part-5-path-objects/